# Excel pivot without aggregate (mac)

Tags: excel

I'm trying to reorganize the data that I have on an excel file but with little to no success.
I usually use google sheets which has an amazing `query` function but using gdocs is not an option on this case. I'm using **excel for mac** I can't seem to find anything similar to that.

This is the data I have:

| index | page | year | label | value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | page1 | 2000 | A | 43 |
| 1 | page1 | 2000 | B | 65 |
| 1 | page1 | 2000 | C | 23 |
| 2 | page1 | 2001 | A | 44 |
| 2 | page1 | 2001 | B | 65 |
| 2 | page1 | 2001 | C | 11 |
| 3 | page2 | 2001 | X | 33 |
| 3 | page2 | 2001 | T | ORANGE |
| 3 | page2 | 2001 | P | 1.33% |
| 4 | page2 | 2001 | X | 12 |
| 4 | page2 | 2001 | T | RED |
| 4 | page2 | 2001 | P | 1.00% |

I need to transform that data into this (on another sheet)

| page | label | 2000 | 2001 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| page1 | A | 43 | 44 |
| page1 | B | 65 | 65 |
| page1 | C | 23 | 11 |
| page2 | X |  | 33 |
| page2 | P |  | ORANGE |
| page2 | T |  | 1.33% |
| page2 | X |  | 12 |
| page2 | P |  | RED |
| page2 | T |  | 1.00% |

Thank you

Comment: If you have O365 for the Mac, you could use Power Query.